# Retrieve complete group of nested tags

Tags: c#, string-operations

I have a text string (svg-file) where I need to retrieve the complete branch of nested TAGs for a given starting position. The algorithm should return the minimal amount of TAGs with even opening and closings.

```
<g... <g... </g... <g... </g... </g>
```

---

Some sample data:

```
<g id="shape57-240" v:mID="57" v:groupContext="shape" transform="translate(550.246,-1356.2)">
        <title>Entscheidung.54</title>
        <desc>Modelcoding</desc>
        <v:userDefs>
            <v:ud v:nameU="msvThemeColors" v:val="VT0(36):26"/>
            <v:ud v:nameU="msvThemeEffects" v:val="VT0(16):26"/>
        </v:userDefs>
        <v:textBlock v:margins="rect(4,4,4,4)"/>
        <v:textRect cx="42.5197" cy="1583.12" width="85.04" height="42.5197"/>
        <g id="shadow57-241" v:groupContext="shadow" v:shadowOffsetX="1.44" v:shadowOffsetY="-1.44" v:shadowType="1"
                transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1.44,1.44)" class="st9">
            <path d="M0 1583.12 L21.26 1561.86 L42.52 1561.86 L63.78 1561.86 L85.04 1583.12 L63.78 1604.38 L42.52 1604.38 L21.26
                         1604.38 L0 1583.12 Z" class="st10"/>
        </g>
        <path d="M0 1583.12 L21.26 1561.86 L42.52 1561.86 L63.78 1561.86 L85.04 1583.12 L63.78 1604.38 L42.52 1604.38 L21.26
                     1604.38 L0 1583.12 Z" class="st23"/>
        <text x="13.52" y="1580.12" class="st12" v:langID="1034"><v:paragraph v:horizAlign="1"/><v:tabList/>Modelcoding<v:newlineChar/></text></g>
```

---

Here is the solution I finally came up with. The problems I had yesterday where related to a corrupt SVG structure; therefore I place a breakup in the while loop after 40 iterations.

```
    string ExtractTAG(string s, int offset)
    {
        string org = s.Substring(offset, s.Length - offset);
        s = s.Substring(offset + 1, s.Length - offset - 1);

        int shift = 0;
        int level = 1;
        int n = 0;
        int nextClose;
        int nextOpen;
        int CheckPoint = 0;

        while (level != 0 && n < 40)
        {
            nextClose = s.IndexOf("</g>");
            nextOpen = s.IndexOf("<g ");

            if (nextClose == -1)
            {
                //no next closing point => corrupt file
                return "";
            }
            if (nextClose < nextOpen || nextOpen == -1)
            {
                CheckPoint = nextClose;
                level = level - 1;
            }
            else if (nextClose > nextOpen)
            {
                CheckPoint = nextOpen;
                level = level + 1;
            }

            shift = shift + CheckPoint;
            n = n + 1;
            s = s.Substring(CheckPoint + 1, s.Length - CheckPoint - 1);
        }
        if (n == 40)
        {
            return "Length could not be determined after 40 iteration - SVG might be courrupt";
        }
        return org.Substring(0, shift + n + 4);
    }
```

Comment: Might it be easier to parse the XML and get data from the tags that way?

Comment: Also, a sample of the data and what you are trying to extract would help.

Comment: Sample data added!

Comment: SVG is XML. See marked duplicate for how to parse it.

Comment: As I need to write back to the file at determent positions, depending on these nested g-elements, I really would prefer to do it without parsing the xml as I'm more familiar with this kind of string operations. The above solution works, but in large files I get trapped in loops

Comment: How can I get rid of the [dublicate] flag. It's not a dublicate question as I explained.